# PHP CURL - Why is my HTTP_REFERER script not working?

Tags: php, http, curl, referer

I need help fixing my script so that visitors through the script will show up in analytics as coming from tumblr.com.

When I visit my php page, it shows http://prntscr.com/aczmvi

Heres my script---->

```
    <?php
print curl_spoof("http://whatsmyreferer.com/");
function curl_spoof($url)  
{   

$curl = curl_init();

$header[] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//Spoof the agent
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.17 Safari/537.36');

//Spoof the Referer
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER,  "http://tumblr.com");


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    if (!$html = curl_exec($curl))
{ 
    $html = file_get_contents($url); 
}
    curl_close($curl);

return $html;
   }

   ?>
```

Ideas?

Comment: Any ideas?  I know theres plenty of people who've done this before (:f

Comment: I think it's working fine and that site isn't showing it correctly.  The Referer header is getting sent with the request.

Comment: The referring header is not showing up in analytics.  This is the goal.  ideas?

Comment: By analytics do you mean a stat tracker like google analytics? cURL doesn't load any javascript so nothing like that will pick up the fact that it access the website.

Comment: I see, well then my other option is on my second thread --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949427/how-to-redirect-traffic-that-comes-from-certain-domains-to-a-new-url