# How to redirect traffic that comes from certain domains, to a new url

Tags: referer

I need to redirect traffic for all the visitors coming from a bunch of domains, but they all have the same page.

So all referrers like this:

```
hxxp://domain1.com/search.php
hxxp://domain2.com/search.php
hxxp://domain3.com/search.php
```

So when these visitors come to my page, they will be redirected through another url, however all other referring visitors will go to the site.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file, assuming YourNewDestination.com is the desired destination:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /search\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://YourNewDestination.com
```

Comment: Lovely bud!  QUESTION--> Is there a way to simply redirect any domain that has the page "search.php" ?  All referring domains that I want directed actually have that same page.  (:

Comment: so wed be redirecting funny.com/search.php , dogs.com/search.php,

Comment: See edited answer. Now it just looks to see that the referrer is a string that ends in "/search.php". Please accept answer if it is correct. Thanks.

Comment: hm, no.  I place the code in htaccess on this site http://bit.ly/1YODqaM and  placed a different url in the "yournewdestination.com".  Then I sent traffic.  No traffic was redirected to the "newdestination.com".  So then I created a link to test, on another domain.com/search.php, it takes me to the main site, but since its referring from search.php, it should be taking me to the "newdestination.com".  Ideas?

Comment: You should look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for the full discussion of this.